# Is there a Mathematica equivalent of Eq() in sympy

Tags: equation-solving

In sympy, the Eq() function could help to visualize a system of equation like below, I am wondering is there an equivalent of Eq() in Mathematica? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Have you seen `CoefficientArrays[]` already?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there an Mathematica equivalent of Eq() in sympy

Yes, it is called `==` which is much better than sympy's `Eq()` because it shows the equation as one will see it in a book and hence easier to read.

```
A = {{2, -1}, {-1, 2}};
bVector = {3, 0};
xVector = {x, y};
```

Now do

```
eq = A . xVector == bVector
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the display part you show, you can do

```
ApplySides[MatrixForm, eq]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

I do not exactly know what OP expects, but I thought I give a place to start.

**Setup.** Define matrix and vector:

```
A = {{2,-1},{-1,2}};
b = {3,0};
```

Define unknown and equations:

```
unknown = {x,y};
equation = Thread[A.unknown == b];
```

**Solving.** The simplest is

```
Solve[equation,unknown]
(* {{x->2,y->1}} *)
```

Alternatively, since this is a linear system, you could use

```
LinearSolve[A,b]
(* {2,1} *)
```

**Visualization.** Just calling

```
equation
```

gives

[image]

which is the default visualization, and I am usually happy with this. I sometimes use

```
TableForm[equation]
```

which gives

[image]

To get something closer to what you have in your question, you could define

```
visualize[eq_]:=Infix[{MatrixForm[Map[First,eq]],
                       MatrixForm[Map[Last,eq]]},"=="];
```

Now

```
visualize[equation]
```

gives

[image]